# Emacs CEDET and system include paths

Tags: emacs, cedet

I'd like to add path to the openMPI library headers. So, after i found all openMPI headers are in /usr/lib/openmpi/include/* i added these two lines to my .emacs:

```
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/lib/openmpi/include" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/lib/openmpi/include" 'c++-mode)
```

I think this is ok, but it's not working!
This is the result of semantic-c-describe-envirnoment command:

> This file's system include path is:
>       /usr/include
>       /usr/local/include/
>       /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/
>       /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include-fixed/
>       /usr/include/

Can't figure out what's wrong or what i'm missing

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have no explanation as to why it doesn't work. Since I had the same problem, experimenting I found a fix that worked for me:

```
(defun my-semantic-hook ()
  (semantic-add-system-include "/usr/lib/openmpi/include" 'c-mode)
  (semantic-add-system-include "/usr/lib/openmpi/include" 'c++-mode))
(add-hook 'semantic-init-hooks 'my-semantic-hook)
```

Comment: Just to chime in, this is STILL the only way to get this to work.

Comment: This worked for me too.  I believe irony and/or company-irony were causing issues as well.  After commenting them out everything works.

Answer (score 2):

I've given this example a try, and find that it "works for me".  Your best bet is to join the cedet-devel mailing list where it will be easier to help your through the process of debugging the issue in your Emacs.

https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/cedet-devel